# Shared sites/all/libraries/ directory is not recognized by contrib modules

Tags: 9, multi-sites

I'm trying to put the `colorbox` javascript library to the shared `sites/all/libraries` directory but it is not recognized by the `colorbox` module. The same seems to go for the `jquery.cycle` library. I just copied the `libraries` directory from sites/nias.cz/libraries` to the shared one. The final example path is

```
sites/all/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js
```

Comment: The location needs to be just libraries/ at the same level where sites/, core/ etc. reside, the webroot.

Comment: Drupal 8+ installed in the libraries directory so the path becomes **"libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries have changed since Drupal 7. Libraries are no longer stored in *sites/all/libraries*. Drupal 8+ [uses Composer and stores third-party libraries in *libraries*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies#third-party-libraries).